# Google Sheets Script TimeStamp will not Return AM/PM nor 24-hour time

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working with a Google Script (see below) to timestamp when actions occur on the spreadsheet.  The script works great EXCEPT for 1 problem.  The timestamp returns data in 12-hour format, but will not indicate whether it is AM/PM.  If the script triggers at 16:00:00, the time stamp reads 4:00 AM instead of PM.  Can someone help me please?  I have already tried adding the AM/PM to the `timestamp_format`, but then the script fails to run.

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "America/Chicago";
  var timestamp_format = "MM/dd hh:mm"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Customer Update Confirmation 4";
  var timeStampColName = "TimeStamp 4";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('COVERED'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.

  var responseArray = ["TimeStamp 1", "TimeStamp 2","TimeStamp 3","TimeStamp 4","TimeStamp 5","TimeStamp 6"];
  var questionArray = ["Freight Broker 1 Day Follow Up", "Freight Broker Pickup Day Follow Up", "Load Pickup Update 1","Load Pickup Update 2","Load Pickup Update 3"];

  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRow();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();//get values and place them inside array 
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName); //get index position inside the array

 for(var i = 0; i < questionArray.length ; i ++){   
      if (headers[0].indexOf(responseArray[1]) > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == (headers[0].indexOf(questionArray[i])+1) ) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!

          var cell = sheet.getRange(index, (headers[0].indexOf(responseArray[i])+1) ); 
          var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
          cell.setValue(date); 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand about `I have already tried adding the AM/PM to the timestamp_format, but then the script fails to run.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I add the AM/PM to the timestamp format.  See Below where I added AM/PM.  this causes the script to fail and not run.

      var timestamp_format = "MM/dd hh:mm AM/PM"; // Timestamp Format.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When `"MM/dd hh:mm AM/PM"` is used to `format` of `Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)`, the error occurs, because `AM/PM` cannot be used for the format string. When you want to show "AM" or "PM", please use `a` like `"MM/dd hh:mm a"`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) and [Ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) But, is this the direct solution of your question?

Comment: I either need the TimeStamp to show AM/PM or to show in a 24 hour time format.  Either will work, although, a 24-hour time format is preferable.  Your suggestion has been implemented with using only an "a" and the script returns a return, so as long as that solution works when it is PM then it is a satisfactory solution. Thank you

Comment: @MattLeavell Did the solution in the comments from Tanaike work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The `Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)` method uses Java's SimpleDateFormat. As a result, to get AM/PM to appear in your cell you need to use the following `timestamp_format`:

```
var timestamp_format = "MM/dd hh:mm a"; // Timestamp Format.
```

The only difference here is the `a` added at the end of the string. This `a` is the AM/PM marker for `SimpleDateFormat` and will always be capitalized.

You can find this information by viewing the [Utility Class Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) which will lead you to Java's [SimpleDateFormat Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

I hope this answer helps others who come across this question in the future.